# How important are the grades in some of the master courses for the PhD admission (with forward view on France, US, UK)?

Tags: phd, masters, grades

I was enrolled in MS (computer science) studies some 7 years ago and I acquired 40 credits with rather low grades (5, 6, 7, 8, medium could be 6.7). This MS program was a bit different from my BS studies and also I had to work in almost full time job and there were other problems. I completed BS (physics) studies with the average grade of 9.7 and I had and I have quite a bit ambitions. So - these 1.5 years of my life was some bad period. It can be explained partially with my ambitions to master quantum field theory (initially) and then theoretical  computer science and AI (later).

Now I am restarting my MS studies from the scratch. I learned all these years myself, in my own pace (textbooks, online lectures, articles, PhD thesis - both computer science and math - there are really cool connections for building deep learning theory), mostly I tried to achieve the level when I could freely read and do the advanced staff, like HoTT and theory of deep learning (beyond the empirics that is so cool in the industry). And while I still have to work, I am far more confident about my job. So - I feel that my MS studies will be far better this time.

Now the question is about 16 (from 40) credits which I am eligible to transfer from my previous studies. I am doing utmost to have the highest grades now, but I should decide whether I want those 16 credits with 5-8 grades on my diploma, or maybe it is better to go through these courses again (it will be easy) and get better grades?

I have 2 arguments in my mind:

1. if I am transferring grades from my previous period, then I have prospect to shorten my studies from 4 semesters to 3 semesters. There is no monetary reason, but I would like to be PhD studies eligible sooner.
2. my goal is to enroll in some PhD (computer science, AI, deep learning theory, connections with math) studies in France, US or UK. When I told that I learned myself, it meant, that I really took the advanced staff. So, I am setting my bar very high - Grande Ecoles or the best in US, UK. I am doing programming, math and I am writing some stuff for possible articles, so - I hope that will have more or less some papers by the time I will apply for PhD studies. But the question is - how important will be the grades for those 16 credits during the application process?

I am pretty sure, those 5-8 look very bad, but from the other side I hope that I can explain the reason for this and I hope and plan that I will put the best grades in the remaining courses plus some very good research articles in the other plate of weights? Can it work?

Resp., **the question is - can the best grades in the remaining courses (44 as opposite to 16), the best master thesis (20 credits) and the important research articles outweigh the bad grades for 16 credits in my diploma wrt the enrollment prospects in PhD studies in France, US, UK?**

I am pretty sure that the competition for BS and MS studies are pretty fierce and formal. But the enrollment in PhD studies can be more intricate matter. It is pretty formal in my present country (Eastern Europe, here I can not hope to pursue PhD studies with such grades on my diploma, I can only have self-financed studies), but I guess - it can be pretty different in France, US, UK? Maybe they have no formal formulas for grades+thesis+papers and maybe they evaluates the prospective PhD studies how well they can do research, what advanced skills they have, how hard working they can be in acquiring the frontier material, do they have incentives and are they willing to transfer the research output to the industry and maybe create their own startup? And these things are only partially reflected in the grades that were acquired some 7 years ago.

And the last thing. Maybe money can solve this problem? Maybe I can plan to have such a good job (or startup) that I can afford to pay for my PhD studies and then the admission criteria can be relaxed wrt those 16 credits?